# Center aligned table cell problem

Tags: tables

I'm preparing a table in `babel` environment. Everything was good except I have created a multi-line column in the table. I have used `\shortstack` for multi-line centered aligned text.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*4c c}
    \toprule
    কলাম ১ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{কলাম ২} & কলাম ৩ & \shortstack{কলাম ৪\\ লম্বার টেক্সট} \\
    \midrule
    ১   & ১২     & ১৪    & ১৬৮  & ১\\
    ২   & ১১    & ১৫   & ১৬৫ & ২\\
    ৩   & ১০    & ১৬     & ১৬০ & ৩\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

New problem is identified in the figure using yellow marker. I am intended to make those columns **be centered both vertically and horizontally**. How to achieve that? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with all of the properties of the `\shortstack` macro. But it would seem that using an ordinary `tabular` environment solves you formatting issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = fonts ids]{bengali}
\babelfont[bengali]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant=0.3]{Kalpurush}
\babelcharproperty{`।}{locale}{bengali}
\babelprovide[maparabic,alph=alphabetic]{bengali}

% define a wrapper macro for the 'tabular' environment:
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} ccccc @{}}
    \toprule
    কলাম ১ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{কলাম ২} & কলাম ৩ & \mytab{কলাম ৪\\ লম্বার টেক্সট} \\
    \midrule
        ১   & ১২     & ১৪    & ১৬৮  & ১\\
        ২   & ১১    & ১৫   & ১৬৫ & ২\\
        ৩   & ১০    & ১৬     & ১৬০ & ৩\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```